# python code using Reticulate in R notebook is very slow and hangs every time

Tags: r, reticulate

I have been trying to use reticulate within the R notebook to run the python code. However after running few commands, the python codes are extremely slow and eventually the entire R notebook run crashes.

Should I be doing something different to make python code run smoothly using the reticulate package.

For example, below is the code I run and then the whole notebook hangs  specially if I use a moderately heavy file of about 80 MB. I am using a 16GB laptop and memory shouldn't be an issue. Am i doing something wrong here.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
```

```{python}
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```{python}
iris_data =  pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
```

```{python}
iris_data.head()
iris_data.columns
iris_data.values
```
````

Comment: Read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: We don't know what you're doing now, so we can't help you figure out how to improve it. Can you generate a [mcve] of your problem with code, data, and error messages? Once we can reproduce your problem, we can try to solve it

Comment: For what it's worth, R also crashes on me when I run this code in an RMarkdown. Running a newer Macbook Pro, memory shouldn't be an issue.